# Internet Explorer restricted this web page from running scripts or ActiveX controls pop up window

Tags: sharepoint-online

This pop up window appearing in SharePoint Online intranet page: Internet Explorer restricted this web page from running scripts or ActiveX controls. 
It is affecting almost for more than 5000 users. I know, how I can configure it to my computer from IE Options->Tools->Advanced->Security and then check for Allow active content to run in files on My Computer. But this is applying only for my computer. How can I enable it for all users? Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

To apply IE settings for all users you need to ask your system administrator to create/modify the **domain policy** to *Allow active content to run in files*

BTW, I think it isn't a SharePoint question!!

Comment: How to create domain policy?Is it related with coding part?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742376.aspx

Comment: How can I define that which web part is not allowing to run active content?How can I found from where it comes?